# Question about light and distance

Tags: visible-light, spacetime, universe, speed, distance

If we see into the past with light and distance travelling so we can’t see things how they are currently, only how they were in the past; and James Webb took a photo from the beginning of the universe theoretically. But if we are seeing it as it was 13.8 billion years ago is there a possibility that the universe has already ended or possibly ended years and years ago and we just don’t know or understand anything about it ? So we are behind and can’t tell ?

Comment: Because time is not absolute and you live now, you cannot say that universe is ended.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a possibility that the universe has already ended or possibly ended years and years ago and we just don’t know or understand anything about it ?

Not the end of the universe as such, but there is certainly the possibility that a catastrophic event has happened somewhere in the universe, but we have no way of detecting it due to the finite speed of light. A [gamma-ray burst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma-ray_burst) or a [false vacuum decay event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_vacuum) could be on its way towards us, and we would have no way of knowing about it until it hit us.